# Socket programming with PyQt

Tags: multithreading, sockets, pyqt, pyqt5

I would like to write a simpe program that can handle a server-client connection (1:1 connection is enough) in PyQt. I want to send a message from the server to the client and then reply to server with another message. 
I have found a chat application that uses PyQt. 
Here is the link: 
http://www.mranuran.com/blog/2017/08/04/creating-graphical-chat-application-using-pyqt-and-socket/

I have tried the code, but unfortunately it did not work. I ran the server.py first and then the client.py. But something was wrong with the connection. This line:

```
print(“[+] New server socket thread started for ” + ip + “:” + str(port))
```

was never executed.

Comment: Change TCP_PORT = 80 to another port,  for example 9000, port 80 is used for internet connection so it is probably used.

Comment: OMG I went through every line, but I did not see it :) Thanks!